# Block the loading of partial views in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Can we block the generation of informations inside modal.

If i have a list of user, and each of them have a modal associated. But there is a lot of informations inside that modal.

So I would like to block them until the user open the modal

Code :

```
@users.each do |u|
  <li>
    u.name
    ****    -> Modal info <- ****
  </li>
end
```

So I would like to display the list of users within the informations inside his modal

Do you know a way to do that

Comment: Please post your code. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edit the title, it should be more clear, I can post my code but I think you don"t really need it because it's a general question about an hypothetic existance of a tool

Comment: So unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to block the generation of my code inside the modals. My index page render a list of user and each of them have a modal with a lot of informations. Can I block the code inside the modal until I open it ?

Comment: @MarkThomas, I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: You can lazy-load the user info through AJAX. Make your `UsersController#show` respond to AJAX requests, and write some javascript that sends AJAX request on opening a modal, and populates the modal with the data returned from the server.

Comment: @Aetherus, cool, it's can be a good solution :) Thanks dude !